# How to skip an undefined item while using with_items in Ansible

Tags: loops, ansible

Example:

```
- name: Check the count of numberServers matches that of jvm variables
  assert:
    that: item|count|int == numberServers
    msg: JVM count for {{item}} doesn't match numberServers
  with_items:
    - "{{ JVMs_ }}"
    - "{{ jvmName }}"
    - "{{ jvmSize }}"
    - "{{ jvmHeap }}"
```

So say `JVMs_` is not defined, and I want the task to run for the rest of the items.

**NOTE:* Have tried using `when`; it skips the whole task if the condition  is not satisfied.

Also, creating separate tasks is a not a good option, since I have much more than 4 items to loop over.

Comment: have you tried `when: {{item}}`? Show your output.

Comment: @tedder42 This is the error I get when I tried the above

`TASK [Input-Validation : Check the count of numberServers matches that of jvm variables] *****************************************************************************
fatal: [34.209.242.130]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'JVMs_' is undefined"}
`

Comment: hmm, how about, in with_items, to do `{{JVMs|default('')}}` or similar? You might be able to do `|omit`, try some things like that.

Comment: aha, `|default(omit)`

Comment: Ok, default (omit) isn't really skipping the task, but executing it (which is a step better) but then the task i.e. assertion is failing since omit doesn't match.

Comment: see if you can fix **that** with a 'when'.

Comment: This seems is working. Is there or can there be anything better ?
`  with_items:
    - "{{ JVMs_ | default('omit')}}"
  when: item != 'omit'`

Comment: Omit shouldn't be in quotes

Answer (score 3):

In your case, you can use `|default([])`, `with_items` ignore empty lists:

```
- name: Check the count of numberServers matches that of jvm variables
  assert:
    that: item|count|int == numberServers
    msg: JVM count for {{item}} doesn't match numberServers
  with_items:
    - "{{ JVMs_ | default([]) }}"
    - "{{ jvmName | default([]) }}"
    - "{{ jvmSize | default([]) }}"
    - "{{ jvmHeap | default([]) }}"
```